# How to copy one Arraylist to another Arraylist upto specific Index?

Tags: java, android

I have an arraylist of model class type where model class has some data. I want to copy the contents of this arraylist to another same type of arraylist but just upto starting 8 index. How to do this?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList(int,%20int)

Comment: write a loop that runs for 8 iterations and copy the elements over by referencing index by index

Comment: A little search and doc reading should get you there pretty fast. I'm really inclined to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

How about `List::`[sublist](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int))?

```
 ArrayList<YourType> al = initializeList();
 ArrayList<YourType> newList = new ArrayList<YourType>(al.subList(0, uptoThisIndex));
```

It allows getting a view of the list between two indices.

If you set the first index to `0` you get the result you desire.

Comment: You don't need to instanciate a new ArrayList, just do newList = al.subList(0, uptoThisIndex)

Comment: @Denis OP needs a copy of the original list. sublist returns a view. Modifying the view means modifying the original list.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this:

```
    ArrayList <YourDataType> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<YourDataType>();
    ArrayList <YourDataType> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<YourDataType>();


     int limit = 3 ; //assuming you want to copy till 3 elements.
    for(int i=0;i<limit;i++)
        arrayList2.add(arrayList1.get(i));
```